# Save uploaded image to database on Flask

Tags: python, html, sql, flask

I'm learning Python and using Flask to develop an application and one of the features is that a user can upload a profile picture and that image should be saved in the database.

I have a form where the user can upload a file, like this:

```
<form action="/myprofile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="picture" placeholder="Picture" type="file">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then, in the application.py file I'm handling it like this:

```
@app.route("/myprofile", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def myprofile():
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET role = :role, picture = :picture, linkedin = :linkedin WHERE id = :user_id", role = request.form.get("role"), picture = request.files("picture"), linkedin = request.form.get("linkedin"), user_id = session["user_id"])

        return render_template("home.html")
    else:
        return render_template("myprofile.html")
```

This is returning an Internal Server Error. Does anyone have any idea why?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I answer you. In case this doesn't help then Add the error code you get.Also if my solution with SQLAlchemy then I may upload my repository by using Vanilla SQLite (it will take some time) because anyway I am planning to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see what error you get, however I want to share one of my previous answer regarding uploading an image into Flask.
I prepared a mini app that is doing just what you asked for, using flask, flask_sqlalchemy (with sqlite3), html and Bootstrap.

You can find the full code here(I will update it with more secure file uploads) as the one given here is only a small part:

[FULL CODE](https://github.com/Koubae/Programming-CookBook/tree/master/Back-End/Python/External%20Libraries/Flask/Flask_website_examples/03%20Uploads/B%20Version)

---

### Some Code from my Github Repo

---

## Initiate the database, configs and Picture table for the databse

> > In class FileContent(db.Model):

- data = file.read()  It saves in database the Binary version of thefile
  -render_file = render_picture(data).  It saves the decode version, so that you can you see it for render it in the webpages.

  ```
    # Built-in Imports
    import os
    from datetime import datetime
    from base64 import b64encode
    import base64
    from io import BytesIO #Converts data from Database into bytes

    # Flask
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for, send_file # Converst bytes into a file for downloads

    # FLask SQLAlchemy, Database
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


    basedir = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'data.sqlite')

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = basedir
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'dev'
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

    # Picture table. By default the table name is filecontent
    class FileContent(db.Model):

        """ 
        The first time the app runs you need to create the table. In Python
        terminal import db, Then run db.create_all()
        """
        """ ___tablename__ = 'yourchoice' """ # You can override the default table name

        id = db.Column(db.Integer,  primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
        data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, nullable=False) #Actual data, needed for Download
        rendered_data = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)#Data to render the pic in browser
        text = db.Column(db.Text)
        location = db.Column(db.String(64))
        pic_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
        def __repr__(self):
            return f'Pic Name: {self.name} Data: {self.data} text: {self.text} created on: {self.pic_date} location: {self.location}'
  ```

### Upload route, here is where the picture its sent to databse and processed with correct data

> > So here is what is going on in the app route:

- def render_picture(data)  --> Takes the bites raw version of the pic and return the decode version, so that it can be used to be display on the web.
- data = file.read() : This is the raw data.This can be used for downloading the pic from database
- render_file: decoded file so you can retrieve it and the render in the web page

  #Render the pics, this Function converts the data from
  request.files['inputFile'] so that in can be displayed

  ```
  def render_picture(data):

      render_pic = base64.b64encode(data).decode('ascii') 
      return render_pic


  @app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
  def upload():

     file = request.files['inputFile']
     data = file.read()
     render_file = render_picture(data)
     text = request.form['text']
     location = request.form['location']

     newFile = FileContent(name=file.filename, data=data, 
     rendered_data=render_file, text=text, location=location)
     db.session.add(newFile)
     db.session.commit() 
     flash(f'Pic {newFile.name} uploaded Text: {newFile.text} Location: 
     {newFile.location}')

     return render_template('upload.html')
  ```

### INDEX Route

```
# Index It routes to index.html where the upload forms is 
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/')
def index():

    return render_template('index.html')
```

### INDEX HTML with the Form

```
<form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- File Upload-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputFile">File input</label>
            <input class="form-control-file" type="file" name="inputFile">
        </div>

        <!-- Location -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="location">Location</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="location">
        </div>

        <!-- Text -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Write Text</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="text" id="text" rows="5" placeholder="Add a Description"></textarea>
        </div>

        <!-- Submit -->        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I just didn't get how you choose in which table you save your image. I have an entity called user_photo, that has a user_id and a column to save the binary.

Comment: I edit my answer a bit. If you mean in whic table of the database then actually I save it twice in 2 different version.  Look at the class class FileContent(db.Model): you will see

Comment: data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, nullable=False) #Actual data, needed for Download
rendered_data = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)#Data to render the pic in browser